# Run a command while other process runs

Tags: command-line, gpu

I think this question must have been asked before but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I am training a neural net on a server with CentOS 7. I am using Linux screens. On one particular screen I have attached 4 GPUs. I am suspecting that my training is not using them but I don't know how to find out for sure because I'd have to stop the training to run something like `nvidia-smi` to get info about GPU usage. Then obviously no GPUs are being used. I also cannot run the command outside of the screen.

I have tried to run my training with `nohup` but I then struggled to end it so I am looking for something else.

**Question:** How can I determine what's the GPU usage **during** training?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a script looking something like this:

```
./myprogram &
./myprogram &
./myprogram &
./myprogram &

echo Started ./myprogram instances, now sleeping for 5 seconds
sleep 5

echo Doing "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz"
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz

echo Waiting until all ./myprogram instances are done
wait
```

The above works for me, it lets me see the result of the `cat /proc/cpuinfo` command while the four `myprogram` instances are running. In your case, you would run your training program instead of "myprogram", and your `nvidia-smi` command instead of the `cat /proc/cpuinfo` in my test.

The point is that starting the program(s) with `&` like that means that they run in the background, then you can wait as long as you like using the `sleep` command, then do something to get whatever information you want, and then the `wait` in the end means that you wait until all processes are done; in your case, until the training program is done.

Does something like that work for you?